# How to view the activity logs/schedule of my natural language processing program on gcp

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, nlp, schedule

As the title, I would like to view the schedule/logs of my natural language processing on GCP, so that I can see which step/instance that the program processes on.

In other words, is there any possibility that I can view every process, such as that which instance the program is working on and which instances are done. An example is shown below:

[image: this image]

Comment: You question is so ambigous. How did you process natural language. Through GCP auto ML? Or your own model on AI platform? Just GCE? I don't have any idea about what "instances are done" means

Comment: yes, through GCP auto ML. what I want to know is that when the model is being trained, it has to train, test, verify the data one by one. Is it possible to know the progress? For example, at this time, which stage it is at, training, testing or verifying? Furthermore, which pieces of data have been trained, tested, or verified referring to "instances are done"? Or, when i want to use the model to predict some texts, how to know which pieces of texts is finished predicted and which not.

Comment: In autoML, Google doesn't clarify any information about ML like progress, stage, training etc.. It is like a blackbox.  Not just NLP, but almost autoML products. Google provides you a handy ML service, but does not disclose any ML information In return.

Comment: Is there any other tools or method to trace/visualize this progress?

Comment: All information you can get about progress is limited in some operations. Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/long-operations#get-operation).